# In Symfony2 cannot get a foreign key value using FindbyOne & CreateQueryBuilder

Tags: symfony

A Symfony2 Query is returning all values in an array except one value which is a primary key of an another table. Both in CreateQueryBuilder and FindOneBy I'm not able to get the value but I can get all other values from the table. Why?

```
$repository123 = $em->getRepository('LoginLoginBundle:Clientuserdetails');

$client_userdetail = $repository123->createQueryBuilder('cud')
    ->where('cud.userid = ' . $userid)
    ->getQuery();

$clientuserdet = $client_userdetail->getResult();
```

Here userid is an entity in Clientuserdetails(). It refers to another table userdetails. Even I passed the userid in the query, I can get all the field values except userid.

Comment: Show us some code... I suppose that you try to access this property by referencing its column name, instead use just the entity name.

Comment: no i used the entity name only still its not working..i will show you sample sample code.

Comment: $repository123 = $em->getRepository('LoginLoginBundle:Clientuserdetails');
        $client_userdetail =$repository123->createQueryBuilder('cud')
                            ->where('cud.userid = '.$userid.'')
                            ->getQuery();
        $clientuserdet =$client_userdetail->getResult();

Comment: $repository123=$em->getRepository ('LoginLoginBundle:Clientuserdetails');         $client_userdetail =$repository123
->createQueryBuilder('cud')                             ->where('cud.userid = '.$userid.'')                             
  ->getQuery();         
$clientuserdet =$client_userdetail->getResult();

Comment: here userid is an entity in Clientuserdetails() it refers to an another table userdetails..even i passed the userid in the query, i can get all the field values except userid

Comment: so $clientuserdet->getId() doesn't work?

Comment: Can you post your LoginLoginBundle:Clientuserdetails mapping